# How to obtain QNetworkAccessManager's connection states?

Tags: qt, state, qnetworkaccessmanager

I need to see different connection states of QNetworkAccessManager. How to do it or is it even possible with QT?

Example in QHttp, there is enum state:
[QHttp enum state](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qhttp.html#State-enum)

QTCPSocket, there is SocketState:
[QAbstractSocket state](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractsocket.html#SocketState-enum)

Most important for me is to know when manager is connected to host and just before manager starts to upload data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Phil has mentioned QNetworkAccessManager has abstracted most of the methods. To get the connection state use QNetworkSession before you work with the QNetworkAccessManager.

To get the state of the current session, use this state function ( http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility/qnetworksession.html#State-enum)

Reading the complete documentation here is going to help you much. http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility/qnetworksession.html

Comment: Thank you both. Qnetworksession was what I was looking for. Sorry for I can't give you rep. 'cause I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I posted and connect to the [finished](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished) signal.  This contains the reply that lets you know if the transfer had errors.  There is also the [networkAccessibleChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#networkAccessibleChanged) signal if you want to detect when you go offline.

`QNetworkAccessManager` is higher level than `QHttp` and `QTCPSocket` so they have abstracted away the sockets connection state.